# Returning Derive type List to base type

Tags: c#

I have defined classes as following:

```
public abstract class EmployeeBase
{

}
public class Employee: EmployeeBase
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have written a method as following:

```
List<EmployeeBase> GetData( )
{

  List<Employee> lstEmployees = new List<Employee>();
  return lstEmployees;
 }
```

The code is throwing a type conversion error. I want to make my GetData method generic  with this kind of implementation. How I can do this?

Comment: Why not instantiate `List<EmployeeBase>` within GetData, or change the return type of GetData to `List<Employee>`? More information is needed to determine the correct approach.

Comment: post shows lack of research

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change your implementation of GetData to:

```
List<EmployeeBase> GetData()
{
    List<EmployeeBase> lstEmployees = new List<EmployeeBase>();

    // Add actual Employee objects to lstEmployees

    return lstEmployees;
}
```

Comment: EmployeeBase is a abstract class and GetData method will return entities derived from EmployeeBase. The GetData method should be capable of returning List of any type derived from Employee Base.How I can do that?